# Docker Swarm dynamic ingress

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am new to Docker Swarm, and am standing up a small enterprise instance for an organization that plans to use it in part for developers to deploy custom developed apps to.  We are able to spin up services and expose them on ports:  ie http://dockernode01:8080.  We understand we could proxy them with nginx or similar so that https://apps.org.com/foo proxies http://foo-service:8080.  However, we would like to proxy them - or some subset of them- automatically.  Conceptually I want to configure the proxy with [https://apps.org.com/{0}](https://apps.org.com/%7B0%7D) which proxies http://{0}-service:8080 and not have to modify nginx config every time a developer adds a service.

Is there a way to do this in nginx, or some other tool that will do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use envoyproxy xDS server and connect it to consul to achieve that

Comment: https://github.com/gojek/consul-envoy-xds here's the reference, but you can create your own control plane